# Nuget Package not avalabible in China

Tags: package, nuget, nuget-package

i have a Nuget package on nuget.org. It is not visible to the people of China.
Can some Body have any idea or any guess that why it is like that.

Comment: I do not have a clue about nuget.org - but there might be some regulations which packages are available in which countries.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that it might have something to do with censorship, as China is well-known for doing such types of things. For further information regarding that topic see [Internet censorship in the People's Republic of China - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China)